# Programmatically find an AWS public DNS with Chef

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra

I'm currently using Chef to try and automate deployment of a couple of servers and I'm running into a bit of an issue. Long story short, I need to programmatically find the public dns of an AWS instance, but I can't seem to find any sort of command to do so. The instance is already a node, so I'm looking for something similar to Chef::Config[:node_name] but for the public dns instead (Chef::Config[:node_public_dns] would do the trick...if it existed). I'm sure that this functionality exists in some form since on creation of the node Chef spits out the public_dns field to the screen.

Anyways, thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it by curl'ing the instance's [metadata service,](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html) specifically for `public-hostname`.

Should be something like:

```
http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname
```

Comment: I am trying the same in my chef script. It simply retries 10 times and gives up. Any clue why?

Answer (score 13):

[Ohai](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Ohai) already picks that for you. So just use the node attribute in your recipes:

```
node[:ec2][:public_hostname]
```